# Ambiguity in mapping of APIs with Html

Tags: html, spring, jsp, servlets

I have an API like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "api/Download", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String filename = "aman1234.xlsx";
    String filepath = "/home/aman/aman1/";
    response.setContentType("APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(filepath + filename);
    int i;
    while ((i = fileInputStream.read()) != -1) {
        out.write(i);
    }
    fileInputStream.close();
    out.close();
}
```

and i am making a call to this API with this

```
<form action="api/Download" method="post">
```

Its working fine the first time i use it and the url shows `http://localhost:8080/UploadExcel/api/Download` and everything works but after redirecting to this page again and posting the form , the url maps to `http://localhost:8080/UploadExcel/api/api/Upload` why does this "/api" get added to the URL . when i remove "/api" from both the method and the html element everything works exactly as it should .

Comment: Because you use relative URLs instead of absolute url. In your form use `/api/Download` instead of `api/Download`.

Comment: @M.Deinum 's comment should be converted to an answer - it's short but to the point. Regarding your code: Who are you trying to confuse with implementing a POST request handler in a `doGet` method, setting the response content type first to "text/html" and later to "APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM"? Let alone the concatenation of the file name (assuming that sooner or later it comes from a parameter) - I'd be happily requesting the file `../../../etc/passwd` and various others from your system. There are a lot more problems with this code than just the relative URL